# Discord.py - Infinite Looping Issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My Goal: To loop through a list of discord server channels and relay a message (excluding the server in which message came from)

Current Results: It's looping through and posting to all channels over and over again. Also posting in the channel in which the message originated from.

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('{0} is in the building!'.format(self.user))
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):

        # relay cod messages
        if message.channel.id in cod_chanlist:
            for chan in cod_chanlist:
                if message.channel.id == chan:
                    pass
                else:
                    game_channel = client.get_channel(chan)
                    await game_channel.send('{0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the message was not sent by a bot, and check against the guild of the original message:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    # relay cod messages
    if message.channel.id in cod_chanlist:
        for chan in cod_chanlist:
            game_channel = client.get_channel(chan)
            if game_channel.guild != message.guild:
                await game_channel.send('{0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
```